# Flutter secure storage not storing once app is closed

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

My Flutter app not storing data once app is closed i had seen similar question in stackoverflow but it is not helpful for me here is my code

**Storage.dart**

```
final _storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

Future<String> read(String key) async{
  String val = await _storage.read(key: key);
  return val;
}

Future<void> write({String key, String value}){
  _storage.write(key: key, value: value);
}

Future<void> delete(String key){
  _storage.delete(key: key);
}

Future<void> deleteAll(){
  _storage.deleteAll();
}
```

I am using this file where ever i want to access flutter secure storage it is working as expected until hot reload or exiting the app. Once if i do hot reload or if re-open the app i am not receiving data

Answer (score 1):

Try making the write, delete, and deleteAll functions async with awaits. Example is right here:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage

I'm not sure if that will fix your issue because I don't know when or how you're calling these functions, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Hi, I making a write and read with async functions but still problem exist. When I reload App, I lose data from storage. Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: @marianciu Unfortunately, it could be any number of issues depending on the OS, device, API, etc. Check the logs of the device you're using and look for any key store exceptions. Alternatively, see if there are any open or closed issues that are similar on their github: https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues/96

According to above link, FlutterSecureStorage does not support flutter-web yet.
Maybe you could try https://pub.dev/packages/crypted_preferences to get storage.